# Сделать автоматическое переключение слайда

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребят, нужно сделать автоматическое переключение слайда, уже много что перепробовал, ничего не выходит

```
 jQuery(function ($) {

    var degree = 0;

    function rotateElem(elem) {
        var indexCurent;
        var countElem = $('.circle-container .circle-item').length;
        var indexElem = $('.circle-container .circle-item').index(elem);

        $('.circle-container .circle-item').each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                indexCurent = index;
            }
        });

        $('.circle-container .circle-item.selected').removeClass('selected');

        if (indexCurent < indexElem) {
            degree = degree - ((360 / countElem) * (indexElem - indexCurent));
        }
        if (indexCurent > indexElem) {
            degree = degree + ((360 / countElem) * (indexCurent - indexElem));
        }

        $('.circle-container').css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
        });

        elem.addClass('selected');
    }

    $('.circle-container .circle-item').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var elem = $(this);
        rotateElem(elem);
        appendContent(elem);
    });

});
```

html

```
<div class="circle-carousel">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="wraper">
                <ul class="circle-container">
                    <li class="circle-item selected">
                        <img class="circle-item-image" src="images/thumb-001.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="circle-item-content">
                            <div class="circle-item-title">
                                <!-- новые серии -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-item-desc">
                                <!-- Будь в рядах первых, кто увидит новые серии. -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-item-link">
                                <!-- # -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="circle-item">
                        <img class="circle-item-image" src="images/thumb-002.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="circle-item-content">
                            <div class="circle-item-title">
                                <!-- Обои на рабочий стол -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-item-desc">
                                <!-- Скачай обои -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-item-link">
                                <!-- # -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="circle-item">
                        <img class="circle-item-image" src="images/thumb-003.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="circle-item-content">
                            <div class="circle-item-title">
                                <!-- Познай мир  -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-item-desc">
                                <!-- Изучи историю -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-item-link">
                                <!-- # -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="circle-item">
                        <img class="circle-item-image" src="images/thumb-004.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="circle-item-content">
                            <div class="circle-item-title">
                                <!--Серии -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-item-desc">
                                <!-- Всё о процессе  -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-item-link">
                                <!-- # -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="circle-item">
                        <img class="circle-item-image" src="images/thumb-005.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="circle-item-content">
                            <div class="circle-item-title">
                                <!--  Аксессуары -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-item-desc">
                                <!-- Магазин -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-item-link">
                                <!-- # -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="circle-item">
                        <img class="circle-item-image" src="images/thumb-003.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="circle-item-content">
                            <div class="circle-item-title">
                                <!-- Хочешь быть в рядах первых? -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-item-desc">
                                <!-- Подписывайся на новости и оповещения -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-item-link">
                                <!-- # -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(function ($) {

var degree = 0;
//Функция поиска элемента
function searchElemForRotate(){
  let indexCurent;
  $('.circle-container .circle-item').each(function (index) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      indexCurent = index;
    }
  });
  if(indexCurent===5){
    indexCurent=0
  }else{
    indexCurent++
  };
  //поворот
  rotateElem($('.circle-container .circle-item').get(indexCurent))
}
function rotateElem(elem) {
  var indexCurent;
  var countElem = $('.circle-container .circle-item').length;
  var indexElem = $('.circle-container .circle-item').index(elem);

  $('.circle-container .circle-item').each(function (index) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      indexCurent = index;
    }
  });
  $('.circle-container .circle-item.selected').removeClass('selected');
  if (indexCurent < indexElem) {
    degree = degree - ((360 / countElem) * (indexElem - indexCurent));
  }
  if (indexCurent > indexElem) {
    degree = degree + ((360 / countElem) * (indexCurent - indexElem));
  }

  $('.circle-container').css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
    '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
    '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
    '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
    'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
  });
  //Пришлось переделать, т.к. при повороте приходится работать со всеми элементами
  $('.circle-container .circle-item').addClass(function (index){
    if(index===indexElem) return'selected'
  });
}

$('.circle-container .circle-item').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var elem = $(this);
  rotateElem(elem);
  //appendContent(elem); нет этой функции выдает ошибку отключил
});
//Таймер для поворота
setInterval(searchElemForRotate,3000)
});
```

Comment: Слушай, не мог бы ты сделать еще бесконечную прокрутку, слайдов, просто после шестого они все возвращаются на исходную, а я не знаю как это пофиксить. Буду бесконечно благодарен!

Comment: @IGI1337 я так понял Вы хотите что бы слайдер постоянно крутился. Вот так https://codepen.io/kinshish/pen/gOObpKP